# How to implement the stripe setup intent to support India recurring payments?

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription

I am using Next + python for my project.
And now I have already implemented subscription feature, and it works well.
But my subscription feature does not support India recurring payment, so it causes of issue for India users.

I created setupIntent in backend like following.

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    company = get_object_or_404(
        Company, random_company_id=self.kwargs.pop("random_company_id")
    )
    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, company)

    if company.stripe_customer_id:
        intent = stripe.SetupIntent.create(customer=company.stripe_customer_id)
    else:
        try:
            company_owner = get_company_owner(company)
            customer = stripe.Customer.create(
                name=company.company_name,
                email=company_owner.user.email,
            )
            customer_id = customer.get("id", None)
            company.stripe_customer_id = customer_id
            company.save()
            intent = stripe.SetupIntent.create(customer=customer_id)
        except Exception as e:
            # customer wasn't created correctly, return error
            return Response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response({"client_secret": intent.client_secret}, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

In frontend, I confirmed it with payment method details like following.

```
export const saveCardWithIntent = (
card,
{ companyId, companyName, address1, address2, country, city, state, postalCode },
setAsDefault,
stripe,
pricePlan ) => async (dispatch) => {
dispatch({ type: TYPES.SAVE_INTENT_INITIALIZING });
const intentUrl = `${NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}payments/stripe/customers/${companyId}/setup-intent/`;
const createCustomerUrl = `${NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}payments/stripe/customers/${companyId}/create/`;

const priceParams = {
  interval: pricePlan.interval,
  interval_count: pricePlan.intervalCount,
  amount: Math.round(pricePlan.amount / 100),
};
const {
  data: { clientSecret },
} = await axios.post(intentUrl, priceParams);

const paymentMethodData = {
  payment_method: {
    type: 'card',
    card: card,
    billing_details: {
      name: companyName,
      address: {
        city,
        country,
        line1: address1,
        line2: address2,
        state,
        postal_code: postalCode,
      },
    },
  },
};

const result = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(clientSecret, paymentMethodData);

// // Throw if error key exists!
if (result.error) throw result.error;

const body = {
  paymentMethodId: result.setupIntent.payment_method,
  setAsDefault,
};

// TODO: Create separate dispatches for customer creation for tracking and more granular debug/error reporting:
const postResponse = await axios.post(createCustomerUrl, body);

dispatch({ type: TYPES.SAVE_INTENT_SUCCESS, payload: { postResponse, body } }); //
return body.paymentMethodId;
```

};

To support India Recurring Payment, I put some codes in backend code, but it does not work well.
What is wrong?

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    company = get_object_or_404(
        Company, random_company_id=self.kwargs.pop("random_company_id")
    )
    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, company)

    interval = request.data.get("interval", "month")
    interval_count = request.data.get("interval_count", 1)
    amount = request.data.get("amount", 100)
    
    start_date = int(time.time())
    payment_method_options_data = {
        'card' : {
            'mandate_options' : {
                'reference': '101011',
                'amount': amount,
                'currency': 'usd',
                'amount_type': 'fixed',
                'start_date': start_date,
                'interval': interval,
                'interval_count': interval_count,
                'supported_types': ['india']
            }
        }
    }
    if company.stripe_customer_id:
        intent = stripe.SetupIntent.create(customer=company.stripe_customer_id, payment_method_options=payment_method_options_data)
    else:
        try:
            company_owner = get_company_owner(company)
            customer = stripe.Customer.create(
                name=company.company_name,
                email=company_owner.user.email,
            )
            customer_id = customer.get("id", None)
            company.stripe_customer_id = customer_id
            company.save()
            intent = stripe.SetupIntent.create(customer=customer_id, payment_method_options=payment_method_options_data)
        except Exception as e:
            # customer wasn't created correctly, return error
            return Response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response({"client_secret": intent.client_secret}, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: You said "but it does not work well", but what does that mean exactly? Do you get an error message, or is payment failing, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Well, If it is succeeded, mandate must be added. But not for my case. Thanks.